# React forms hook with Material UI Select input not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

How de Select below the Textfield should load:

[image]

How it actually loads:

[image]

My Select component created using Material UI + React form hook doesn't load the default value. (The component should start with a value selected, that is provided once in the following part of the code)

```
  const clientData = await api.client.getClient(id);
  reset({ ...clientData });
```

It happens inside a useEffect that should run once, when the page is loaded and the id is gotten from the url. The Select code:

```
export const ClientSourceSelect = ({
      control,
      clientSources,
      getValues,
      errors,
    }: ClientSourceSelectProps) => (
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="clientSourceId"
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <>
              <TextField label={value}></TextField>
              <Select onChange={onChange} value={value}>
                {clientSources.map((clientSource) => (
                  <MenuItem key={clientSource.id} value={clientSource.id}>
                    {clientSource.name}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </FormControl>
    );
```

I created the TextField over the Select to test if the value is really loaded, and the value is really displayed over the Select (a uuid corresponding to clientSource.id), so the value itself exists but the Select starts blank. Using the inspector, the li elements have a correct data-value attribute with their corresponding id.

Comment: How you are initializing the form ?

Comment: useForm: **const {
    register,
    control,
    getValues,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();**

Comment: ClientSourceSelect:  **<ClientSourceSelect
            control={control}
            clientSources={clientSources}
            errors={errors}
            getValues={getValues}
          />**

Comment: The ClientSourceSelect is wrapped in a Box component(I'm using styled components): **<FormWrapper component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(updateClientData)}>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation, you can provide default values when calling useForm() hook.

```
const { control } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    clientSourceId: <your default id>
  }
});
```

Your working code can be found in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-sun-7ee953

Comment: The default clientSourceId depends on an API call, for this reason I didn't define it in useForm. So in this case, I should transform the values returned by useForm in states and define them just after the API call promise is resolved?

Comment: In that case you can use `setValue('clientSourceId', 'your value');` also when your api returned.

Comment: You can find the modified code in same sandbox using setvalue().

Comment: after adding defaultValue on form creation, the problem was solved. Tks!